# Winform design X64 doesn't work "The variable usercontrol1 is either undeclared or was never assigned"

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, 64-bit

I created an user control and I added it into a new form, but some errors happened.
Everything is OK in any CPU mode but when I want to switch to X64, design form doesn't show.

Comment: Did you do a clean build after changing to x64?  After switching modes a new executable is created in a different folder in the bin of your project.  Check date of the file to make sure you are using latest.

Comment: Try: Rebuild Solution then restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem and I fixed it. Actually Visual Studio only works with `X86` controls and you can't create a user control in `X64` mode and use it.

You should add a new `class library` in Any CPU mode and build the `class library`. then you can add its `DLL` in your project. Done.

If it doesn't you must go to the `Configuration manager` and set the `Active solution platform` to `X64` also do that for all subprojects.
Remember that build option has to be checked.
and go to the properties of the class library and click on the build tab. then set the `platform target` to Any CPU.

Comment: Not true.   I had x86 windows form project and ran better as x64.  With x86 had large DGV and was getting out of memory.  Going to x64 solved issue.  When changing project properties you just have to remember to to a clean build and the new executable is then put into a different subfolder in the project bin folder.